# How to sum two rows within CASE in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum, case

I'm currently trying to build a SQL Server Agent which should a fix a price issue we do have with our database. This should be a quick fix, hopefully or provider does come up with a more convenient solution. I have the following statement:

```
SELECT 
    CASE
        WHEN KHKVKBelegePositionen.StuecklistenTyp = '0'
            THEN (SELECT KHKVKBelegePositionen.Gesamtpreis) 
        WHEN KHKVKBelegeStuecklisten.Gesamtpreis != '0,00' 
             AND KHKVKBelege.A0Land != 'DE' 
             AND (KHKVKBelegePositionen.Artikelgruppe != '181' OR 
                  KHKVKBelegePositionen.Artikelgruppe != '182' OR 
                  KHKVKBelegePositionen.Artikelgruppe != '183') 
             AND KHKVKBelegePositionen.StuecklistenTyp != '0'
            THEN (SELECT KHKVKBelegeStuecklisten.Gesamtpreis)
        WHEN (KHKVKBelegePositionen.Artikelgruppe = '181' OR 
              KHKVKBelegePositionen.Artikelgruppe = '182' OR 
              KHKVKBelegePositionen.Artikelgruppe = '183') 
             AND KHKVKBelegePositionen.StuecklistenTyp != '0'
            THEN (SELECT KHKVKBelegeStuecklisten.Gesamtpreis) 
        ELSE 
            CAST(KHKVKBelegeStuecklisten.GesamtpreisInternEW as varchar)
    END AS Gesamtpreis
FROM 
    KHKVKBelegeStuecklisten (READUNCOMMITTED)     
INNER JOIN 
    KHKVKBelege ON KHKVKBelegeStuecklisten.Belid = KHKVKBelege.BElid    
INNER JOIN 
    KHKVKBelegePositionen ON KHKVKBelegeStuecklisten.BelID = KHKVKBelegePositionen.BelID
WHERE 
    KHKVKBelegePositionen.BelID = '3519582'
```

Some items do consists from two parts and each one has a value. So the output are 2 lines with 2 values. I want to sum these values to one value, to update a table.

This part I do struggle the most with

```
WHEN (KHKVKBelegePositionen.Artikelgruppe = '181' OR 
      KHKVKBelegePositionen.Artikelgruppe = '182' OR 
      KHKVKBelegePositionen.Artikelgruppe = '183') 
     AND KHKVKBelegePositionen.StuecklistenTyp != '0'
    THEN (SELECT KHKVKBelegeStuecklisten.Gesamtpreis) `
```

On my example, data would be like this:

```
Overall Price
1. 13.75
2. 2.57
```

I need this value merged summed up to be able to update

Comment: Make it easy to assist you - simplify! [mcve]

Comment: `x <> 180 OR x <> 181` will always be TRUE, as long as x is not null. Perhaps you want AND instead of OR?

Comment: the value of Gesamtpreis is a varchar? do you mean that this varchar field has numerical data stored in it and you wish to sum up the values

Comment: Use of hints without keyword WITH is deprecated. Don't create more work for someone in the future. Don't use hints without a **very good** reason. And don't use [nolock](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere) which is the same as READUNCOMMITTED

Comment: `CAST(KHKVKBelegeStuecklisten.GesamtpreisInternEW as varchar)` Why? Your code is obviously trying to create a numeric expression here, so why do you cast this column to varchar (without a length - another bad habit) to then only be implicitly cast back to the datatype of Gesamtpreis (which presumably has highest precedence)?

Comment: I'm just replacing a comma with a dot like this. Our ERP system has a problem when inserting a comma value.